# Taking Advantage of Time Dilation

Tags: space-time, speed

According to Einstein's theory of Special Relativity, one's speed in relation to a relatively stationary object would 'slow down' time on the moving object.

With this in mind, would it be possible to travel in a straight line away from Earth (stationary object) in a space craft able to travel at +90% the speed of light for 2 years and return with significant time dilation?

What technologies have we generated that could reach speeds for significant time dilation (+10 years)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the fist question it is theoretically possible, and it is explained in the popular [Twin Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox) example.

For the second one I'm not sure if there are some advances but as far as I know there is an important problem about relativistic speeds: the mass of the object traveling at such speed increases dramatically <strike>to the point it would weight so much it would collapse</strike>([It wouldn't collapse actually](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29632/reletivistic-mass-as-seen-by-different-observers/29633#29633)).

Comment: Fast moving objects do not collapse, as explained for example here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29632/reletivistic-mass-as-seen-by-different-observers/29633#29633 The relativistic mass is not invariant, so there exists a reference frame in which I (sitting in my chair) am moving at 99.9999% of the speed of light. But yet I am not collapsing. Gravitational collapse depends on other things (namely the stress-energy temsor) than relativistic mass.

Comment: Thanks @mpv , I shall removoe de collapsing part from my answer.

Comment: Additionally, the claim "the mass of the object traveling at such speed increases dramatically" is mistaken, or at best engenders a conceptual confusion better left to the dustbin of history.

Comment: Why do you say it is a mistake? The inertia of the object does actually increase.

Comment: @Py-ser: In what sense are you using 'inertia' in your statement? If you're transplanting the Newtonian 'resistance to acceleration', then yes, it is greater, but then it is not a scalar and depends on direction of applied force, from $\gamma m$ to $\gamma^3 m$, and so is not actually the relativistic mass. The relativistic mass is just another name for total energy anyway.